# Rails Associations - using data on the association table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a question about associations in Rails 2.3.11

I have two models:

- Activities
- Organisations

they have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. But they also have an important and per-activity-organisation `relationship type`. They are connected together via the `activities_organisations` table, which has three columns:

- activity_id
- organisation_id
- rel_type

The `rel_type` can be set as `1` (funding), `2` (extending) or `3` (implementing).

The association works fine and I can call `@activity.organisations` or `@organisation.activities`. But I'd also like to call this depending on the `rel_type` - so that I can for example call *only* an activity's implementing organisation (where `rel_type == 3`)

At the moment I have this (on the Organisations / index view), but I think there must be a nicer way?

```
<%
 @conditions = {}
 @conditions[:organisation_id] = organisation.id
 @reltype = ActivitiesOrganisation.all(:conditions=>@conditions, :group=>:rel_type)%>

<td><% @reltype.each do |r| %><%= r.rel_type %><% end %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

I [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996560/relationship-type-in-rails) but I got stuck trying to include it in my models, and I'm not sure how much of it applies.

Would be extremely grateful for any help!

Thanks,
Mark

**Update:**

Thanks to @ghoppe in the comments, I realised I was being a bit of an idiot... This is my code now:

**Activity Model**

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :activity_organisations
  has_many :funding_activity_organisations, :class_name => "ActivitiesOrganisation", 
              :conditions => {:rel_type => 1}
  has_many :extending_activity_organisations, :class_name => "ActivitiesOrganisation", 
              :conditions => {:rel_type => 2}
  has_many :implementing_activity_organisations, :class_name => "ActivitiesOrganisation", 
              :conditions => {:rel_type => 3}
  has_many :organisations,       :through => :activity_organisations
  has_many :funding_organisations,  :through => :funding_activity_organisations, :source => :organisation
  has_many :extending_organisations,:through => :extending_activity_organisations,:source => :organisation
  has_many :implementing_organisations,:through => :implementing_activity_organisations,:source => :organisation

end
```

**ActivitiesOrganisation Model**

```
class ActivitiesOrganisation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :organisation

end
```

Thanks!

Comment: The question you found implements exactly the relationships you want. Simply change `read_user_articles` to `funding_organizations` and `follow_user_articles` to `extending_organizations`, `:mode` to `:rel_type` add your third `implementing_organizations` and change the rest to match your structure…